# Link that I progress to fails to add the id number to the end of the URL?

Tags: php, html

hopefully somebody might be able to help:

The link below fails to add the id number to the url when it proceeds to that url, so i cant then GET the id from there:

```
<a href="http://localhost/tdurden/root/user.php?id=".$_SESSION["id"]><button id="logoutbtn">Update</button></a>
```

Other times when I header to a location it has worked:

```
header("location: user.php?id=".$_SESSION["id"]);
```

I think it may be something to do with  tags but not sure as wherever I place them it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that you're most likely not inside PHP in an echo statement.

*Something you haven't mentioned in your question.*

First, make sure you've started the session.

As an example and echo the session in the href:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = 12345;
?>

<a href="http://localhost/tdurden/root/user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>"><button id="logoutbtn">Update</button></a>
```

---

HTML source:

```
<a href="http://localhost/tdurden/root/user.php?id=12345"><button id="logoutbtn">Update</button></a>
```

---

You can also use a ternary operator:

```
<a href="http://localhost/tdurden/root/user.php?id=<?php echo isset($_SESSION["id"]) ? $_SESSION["id"] : '' ?>"><button id="logoutbtn">Update</button></a>
```

Or the full `empty()` conditional statement:

```
<a href="http://localhost/tdurden/root/user.php?id=<?php if(!empty($_SESSION["id"]) ) { echo $_SESSION["id"]; } ?>"><button id="logoutbtn">Update</button></a>
```